# Simple natural logarithm inequality

Tags: inequality

I am failing to see why the following is the case, for:

$$0 < a < b$$

we have

$$\frac{b-a}{b}\leq \int_a^b 1/t \ \ dt \leq \frac{b-a}{a}$$

Embarrassing question...

Comment: oh.. I think I see it for the upper bound

Comment: Hint: $\;\frac{1}{b} \le \frac{1}{t} \le \frac{1}{a}\,$ for $\,t \in (a,b) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^+\,$.

Comment: oh brilliant :) I just integrate each part from a to b

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

you can use the first average formula:

if the function $f $ is continuous at

$[a,b] $, then there exists $c\in [a,b] $ such that

$$\int_a^b f (t)dt = f (c)(b-a) $$

and conclude with $f (t)=\frac {1}{t}$

and $0 <a <c <b $.